# Combinations problem of utmost 2 conditions

Tags: combinations

A commitee of 5 from 6 gents and 4 ladies with utmost 2 ladies?
My answer: $$\binom{4}{0}\binom{6}{5}+ \binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{4}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{3}=246$$ ways.
Is it correct?

Comment: Please demonstrate an effort to solve the problem. What have you tried? Where are you stuck at? What can't you understand?

Comment: My answer.4c0*6c5+4c1*6c4+4c2*6c3=
246 ways.
Is it correct?

Comment: Utmost two ladies refers to either 0 ladies, 1 lady, or 2 lady. Make separate cases and then add them!

Comment: The strategy you used to calculate the answer is correct.  However, $246$ is incorrect.  Check your arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks..arithmetic mistake.... 186

Comment: [Wolfram Solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Combination%284%2C0%29*Combination%286%2C5%29%2BCombination%284%2C1%29*Combination%286%2C4%29%2BCombination%284%2C2%29*Combination%286%2C3%29)

Comment: And why at most two women.  That's sexist!

Comment: Thats some where about scientists